# Swift/GeoFire : How to handle when there's no results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire

I have a filtering option in my app that lets users change the radius and location to view products near them, but when there are no results I'd like to show a message but I don't know where to place the logic that handles that.

Code:

```
func observeProducts(at: CLLocation, radius: Double, limitTo: UInt, priceMin: Double, priceMax: Double, onSuccess: @escaping (Product_) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: self.PRODUCTS_GEOFIRE_REF)
    let gfQuery = geoFire.query(at: at, withRadius: radius)

    gfQuery.observe(.keyEntered) { (key, location) in
        if !key.isEmpty {
            self.PRODUCTS_REF.queryLimited(toFirst: limitTo).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    let product = Product_.transform(product: dict, key: snapshot.key)
                    if key == product.productID {
                        if product.price > priceMin && product.price < priceMax {
                            onSuccess(product)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            onFailure()
        }

    }
}
```

And how's its being called:

```
func loadProducts(address: CLLocation, radius: Double, limitTo: UInt, priceMin: Double, priceMax: Double, sortBy: @escaping () -> Void) {
    ARSLineProgress.show()

    self.products.removeAll()

    APIs.Products.observeProducts(at: address, radius: radius, limitTo: limitTo, priceMin: priceMin, priceMax: priceMax, onSuccess: { (product) in
        // WORKS FINE...
        self.products.append(product)

        sortBy()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        ARSLineProgress.hide()
    }) {
            // NOT BEING CALLLED...
            self.errMessage(msg: "Sorry, no products in your area...")
            ARSLineProgress.hide()
    }
}
```

The way it is right now doesn't do anything but keep showing the `ARSLineProgress` loading view, but when there is a product than it shows the products. The only issue I'm having is finding where to place the `onFailure` closure func. I tried putting it inside the `if key == product.productID {}` area but that doesn't even get called when there's no products within the radius...

Comment: Hey, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Yeah! Got it working with a work around. Not the ideal or answer I was aiming for but it works for the mean time

Comment: Oh nice, would you be kind of enough add the answer or just point me towards the right direction, if possible. thanks.